# ionic frame work SSL certificate issue behind corporate network

Tags: certificate

ionic frame work SSL certificate issue behind corporate network.
i am getting the following error:
Error: Write EPROTO 101057795: error 140770FC:SS: routines: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO: unknown protocol: openssl\ssl